# Return non utf-8 responce when read csv

Tags: node.js, csv, google-cloud-storage

In my case I try to read csv file which is available on google cloud storage.
This is my code:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

const file= storage.bucket('my-bucket').file('file.csv')

file.createReadStream({encoding: 'utf8'})
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        console.log(row);
    }) 
    .on('end', (end) => {
        console.log(end)
    })

  });
```

But returns things like :

```
'\u0000D\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000I\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000s\u0000': '\u00005\u00000\u0000'
```

Any idea what may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like every other byte of the data you've read is `00`, the file is probably not UTF-8, but UTF-16.

Try `file.createReadStream({encoding: 'utf16le'})`, or if it's still garbled, `file.createReadStream({encoding: 'utf16be'})`.

Answer (score -1):

One approach could be:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const file = storage.bucket('my-bucket').file('file.csv');

let data = '';
file.createReadStream({encoding: 'utf8'})
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        data += row; // or directly apply as row.toString('utf-8')
        console.log(row);
    })
    .on('end', (end) => {
        // so all is buffered now lets make it readable
        data = data.toString('utf-8');
        console.log(data);
    });
```